# Does GPE work on Eclipse 4.3 Kepler?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, google-plugin-eclipse

Does GPE work on Eclipse 4.3 Kepler?

Comment: No. The reason for the question is that as an Eclipse user for 8 years, I have had several experiences of new versions corrupting my workspace. I would rather avoid problems than jump into them. Do you have an answer to proffer?

Comment: Unzip 4.3 in a different directory and try to add GPE.  Use a different workspace.  That way, you can fall back to 4.2 if you have any problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far so good running the 4.2 GPE version against 4.3. I've only tested a GAE deployment, so Android, GWT, GAE dev server, API Manager are all untried.

Comment: Here is a bug that is tracking the update https://code.google.com/p/google-plugin-for-eclipse/issues/detail?id=221